# Data transfer via Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, tizen

I'm trying to develop a memo app for my Gear S2 that shows my memo written on my phone. Though, I don't know how to send the text to my smartwatch. Doing so via Bluetooth might be the solution. The question is, how can I program it to use it? Thanks for the help.

Edit: Could you give me the code in java or in any other type of language? Beacuse i'm having trouble with that.

Comment: Yes, for android smartphone

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer data between Tizen(Gear) and Android(Mobile) via SAP(Samsung Accessary Protocol). SAP supports both Bluetooth and WiFi.

You can learn about SAP in below site, Samsung Developer official site.
http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/native-companion/setup-sdk

You can also get a simple useful sample application to adopt quickply to your project.
http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/samples/companion

Good luck to you.